# format scientific notation axis labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, axis-labels

In matplotlib axis labeling, when it uses scientific notation, is there a way to change the format of the part that shows what power of ten to multiply by?  For example, if it would by default display as "10e7", I would like it to display as "× $100M".

Clarification in response to auto-generated list of "duplicate" questions: I am not asking how to change the individual tick labels, I am asking how to change the format of the multiplier which is displayed once (neither as part of the individual tick labels nor as part of the axis title).

Comment: The list of duplicates was not automatically generated. They were added by a user with a gold-badge in matplotlib, which means they are trusted by Stack Overflow to have sufficient experience to single-handedly close questions with tag [tag:matplotlib] and add additional duplicates.